# how to make an already compiled elf file execute another command

Tags: linux, scripting, elf

I have a need for when a ELF file gets executed it will execute a command.

For example:
Running `/usr/bin/file` which is an already compiled ELF Binary, execute the command `touch /tmp/file_is_executed`

if I could I'd recompile the code and add the command I want to the source file. However, I do not have the source code so I have to deal with the compiled version.

Comment: What is the scope? Do you want `file` to do extra job when run from your specific shell? Or always, but only for you? Or system-wide? Common solutions are wrappers that execute the actual binary *and* something else, without modifying the binary. But you explicitly required that "it [i.e. ELF] will execute a command". How important is this requirement?

Comment: If all you want is to determine what files are executed, then look at the audit system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need this to happen just for yourself as a quick fix, you could use a function to override the target command:

```
file() { touch /tmp/file_is_executed; command file "$@"; }
```

However, if you want it to track execution of the command from within an opaque application, or when others execute the command, a function won't necessarily be available when you need it. Likewise, if the target executable is called with a full path (i.e. `/usr/bin/file` rather than `file`), you can't use this approach. In these cases you could create your own implementation of the target executable.

Note that no solution changes an ELF executable that you describe in your question. (Patching a binary is a non-trivial operation.)

Worked example for `/usr/bin/file` for just you:

1. Create a script as `~/bin/file.sh` (you might need `mkdir ~/bin` first):

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   touch /tmp/file_is_executed
   exec /usr/bin/file "$@"
   ```
2. Make the script readable and executable

   ```
   chmod a+rx ~/bin/file.sh
   ```
3. Install the script as *the real thing*

   ```
   cp -p ~/bin/file.sh ~/bin/file
   ```
4. Ensure that ~/bin is in your `$PATH` *before* `/usr/bin`

   ```
   export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
   ```

Worked example for `/usr/bin/file` for everyone (you will need root privileges to do this, so something such as `sudo`, `doas`, or `su` will be required):

1. Create a script as `/usr/bin/file.sh`

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   touch /tmp/file_is_executed
   exec "$0.bin" "$@"
   ```
2. Make the script readable and executable

   ```
   chmod a+rx /usr/bin/file.sh
   ```
3. Install the script as *the real thing*

   ```
   mv /usr/bin/file /usr/bin/file.bin &&
   cp -p /usr/bin/file.sh /usr/bin/file
   ```